# Datatables is not displaying the data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

I already include the CDN like that the website provide and still unable to show or display any result even when copy pasted every single line of code.
Here is the CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Here is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</body>
```

Here is the script

```
[
    {
        "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
        "position":   "System Architect",
        "salary":     "$3,120"
    },
    {
        "name":       "Garrett Winters",
        "position":   "Director",
        "salary":     "$5,300"
    }
]
$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: data,
    columns: [
        { data: 'name' },
        { data: 'position' },
        { data: 'salary' }
    ]
} );
```

Comment: You are using the wrong ID while generating the DataTable. Please try `$('#table_id').DataTable(...`

Comment: @PriyankPanchal it is still the same

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve] using either [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @PriyankPanchal here is the link for it [https://jsfiddle.net/fb48zvw6/]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing two things:

1. JQuery library
2. The `data` variable

Please check the solution below.

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$3,120"
  },
  {
    "name": "Garrett Winters",
    "position": "Director",
    "salary": "$5,300"
  }
]
$('#example').DataTable({
  data: data,
  columns: [{
      data: 'name'
    },
    {
      data: 'position'
    },
    {
      data: 'salary'
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<body>
<table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery datatables.js needs jquery.
You should add it before jquery.datatables.js.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


  And you even don't need to define columns in your datatable, datatables does the work itself :



    <body>
       <table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
    </body>



    <script>

    var dataSet = [
      [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
      [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
   
    ];

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').DataTable( {
         data: dataSet,
         columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
         ]
      } );
     } );
    </script>
```